# Other approaches to evaluate $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{4^{x+h}+4^{x-h}-4^{x+\frac12}}{h^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{4^{x+h}+4^{x-h}-4^{x+\frac12}}{h^2}=?$$

I evaluated the limit by using the Hopital rule,$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{4^{x+h}+4^{x-h}-4^{x+\frac12}}{h^2}=4^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4^h+4^{-h}-2}{h^2}=4^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(4)(4^h-4^{-h})}{2h}=4^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\ln4)^2(4^h+4^{-h})}{2}=4^x\times4(\ln2)^2=4^{x+1}(\ln2)^2$$
I want to learn other ideas to solving this problem, so can you please evaluate the limit with other approaches?

Comment: Write the numerator as $4^{x+h}+4^{x-h}-2 \cdot 4^x$ and then see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1809060/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206176/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technique that requires no L'Hopital, Taylor series or anything more complicated that the definition of limit, knowledge of the natural logarithm (e.g. from $\int_1^2\mathrm{d}t/t=\ln 2)$ and continuity of $x\mapsto x^2$:$$\begin{align}4^x\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4^h+4^{-h}-2}{h^2}&=4^x\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(4^h-1)^2}{h^24^h}\\&=4^x\cdot\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4^h-1}{h2^h}\right)^2\\&=4^x\cdot4\cdot\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^h-2^{-h}}{2h}\right)^2\\&=4^{x+1}\cdot(\ln2)^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate on how you got $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^h-2^{-h}}{2h}=(\ln2)^2$ ?

Comment: I didn't. I got: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2^h-2^{-h}}{2h}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\Big|_{x=0}2^x=\ln2$$Instead. Notice the square on the limit in the full post @Etemon

This is a symmetric derivative. It is equal to the standard derivative when the standard derivative exists.

Comment: Oops I wrote the exponent two wrongly... Still I'm not sure which rule you used I know the following rules that connect limits to derivative $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: Ok it's clear now. You used $$f'(h)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

Comment: Nice, thanks @Etemon

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is using the Taylor expansion
$$2\cosh t = e^t+e^{-t} = 2+t^2 + o(t^2)$$

Hence,

\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{4^{x+h}+4^{x-h}-4^{x+\frac12}}{h^2}
& = & 4^x\frac{e^{h\ln 4}+e^{-h\ln 4}-2}{h^2}\\
& = & 4^x\cdot \frac{2+h^2\ln^2 4 + o(h^2)-2}{h^2} \\
& = & 4^x\cdot\ln^2 4 + o(1) \\
& \stackrel{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow} & 4^x\cdot\ln^2 4
\end{eqnarray*}